# MySQL Stored Procedure Multiplication

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `calc_ytd2` (IN val_id INT(11), 
                              OUT frstname VARCHAR(45), 
                              OUT lstname VARCHAR(45), 
                              OUT pay DECIMAL(10,2))
BEGIN
    select fname, 
           lname, 
           (ytdhours * positionpay) 
      into frstname, 
           lstname, 
           pay
      from employees, 
           jobposition
     where idemployees = val_id;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Note = Its my first time playing around with MySQL. Im trying to figure out how to use the multiplication in the select statement so I can call the procedure. Can I even use that in the select statement and if so how can I call the procedure? thanks in advance for the help :)

[image]

Comment: You can call the stored proc like this  `call calc_ytd2(1234, @frstname ,@lstname , @pay)`.  But your sql doesn't seem right.  You have two tables in FROM but no join.

Answer (score 0):

calling procedure like id 12 :

```
set @out1 = null;
call calc_ytd2(12,@out1);
 SELECT @out1;
```

this is an example if you have an output of only 1...